# Is there a convention for naming and placing the manual page file for a command in source tree?

Tags: man, source, conventions

I think the name could be in format

```
<command_name>.<section_number>
```

where the numbers are shown in the description chapter of `man man`.

I use *doc* directory for the file in a repository.

Comment: You have the built manpage instead of the source for it in your source tree?

Comment: @muru many man pages are maintained as troff files, why would that be surprising?

Comment: @StephenKitt I figured if someone's starting a new project now, they'd be using something more convenient.

Comment: Are you using GNU autotools (`automake` and `autoconf`)?

Comment: @muru I have the built manpage there, though I use `help2man` and some script that I have written to build it.

Comment: @Kusalananda no I am not familiar with them, and my application is a script so I do not have to compile it.

Comment: @StephenKitt I am not familiar with troff files. I use my `make-man.sh` to generate the manual page that I store in [git](https://git.launchpad.net/linux-purge/tree/). I want to be able to maintain manual page easily. And as manual pages are not debian specific, I am wondering, if there is a standard place to put the manual page. If I use a troff file, where would I put that then?

Answer (score 1):

Given that your man page is generated from other “source files”, I wouldn’t store it in the repository at all — in my experience, it’s best for a source repository to only store the files you’d actually want to modify directly, not generated files.

If you do want to store it (for example, to avoid requiring `help2man` when building), since you don’t have a directory structure it’s fine to store it alongside the rest of your source files. The `<command_name>.<section_number>` naming scheme you suggest is fine.

Comment: I have installation script for the utility because people may need it when they can not install anything by `apt`. They can not install `help2man` then. Currently I have the file in debian directory, but I may change that.